# Window scroll event fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am working with a Marionette.js app that fetches more data as the user scrolls down the page.

```
setupWindowScrollListener: function() {
            var $window = $(window),
                $document = $(document),
                that = this;

            $window.on('scroll', _.debounce(function() {
                var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
                    wHeight = $window.height(),
                    dHeight = $document.height(),
                    margin = 100;

                if(scrollTop + wHeight > dHeight - margin) {
                    eventer.trigger('fetch:more:products');
                }
            }, 500));
        }
```

The problem is that when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page, the `eventer` is firing off multiple events instead of just one.

**Update**

Code with isLoading check

```
    setupWindowScrollListener: function() {
        var $window = $(window),
            $document = $(document),
            that = this,
            isLoading = false;

        $window.on('scroll', _.throttle(function() {
            if(!isLoading) {
                var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
                    wHeight = $window.height(),
                    dHeight = $document.height(),
                    margin = 100;

                if(scrollTop + wHeight > dHeight - margin) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    eventer.trigger('fetch:more:products');
                    isLoading = false;
                }
            }
        }, 500));
    }
```

Comment: You have to add a boolean "scrollLoader" fired, a check to see if it is true or false, then fire the event, switch the boolean, and a reset of the boolean once your eventer is finished.

Comment: just check that you are only calling setupWindowScrollListener function once otherwise the .on('scroll'... will be bound multiple times to the $window.. alternately, try changing the on(... to $window.off('scroll').on('scroll', ...... to remove ensure that there is only 1 scroll event listener on the $window.

Comment: @BradBaskin sorry, I'm not following. How do you check to see if `setupWindowScrollListener`  is only called once?

Comment: @dennismonsewicz just make sure that the function setupWindowScrollListener is only called from 1 location when the page loads. Somewhere on your page you will have the code setupWindowScrollListener(); just make sure that only appears once. Also, make sure that whatever function is calling setupWindowScrollListener(); only gets called once too, follow the chain to make sure that setupWindowScrollListener() only gets called 1 time on each page load.

Comment: just adding to that... the function may be inside another variable so it could be var page = {setupWindowScrollListener: function() {........}}; In this case you are looking for the function call: page.setupWindowScrollListener();